# ImportError: dll load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found while importing sklearn package

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, openmp, dllimport, sklearn-pandas

> > > import sklearn
> > >
> > > ## version--3.8.0 64-bit

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Users\SAI-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 75, in 
    from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
  File "C:\Users\SAI-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_show_versions.py", line 12, in 
    from ._openmp_helpers import _openmp_parallelism_enabled
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _openmp_helpers: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Tried hard to solve it in IDLE but it didn't got rectified. Finally overcame it by installing anaconda IDE and using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried hard to solve it in IDLE but it didn't got rectified. Finally overcame it by installing anaconda IDE and using jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same issue.
I am having Python version: 3.7.4 and scikit-learn version: 0.22. 
I resolved this by downgrading scikit-learn to older version using following command:

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

Just in my project's virtual environment, I downgraded sklearn library. 
This might help. 
If anybody have more optimal solution, Kindly share.